# How do I add a fade in?

Tags: jquery, random, quotes, fade, fadein

How would I add a fade in to this?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var myQuotes = new Array(); 
  myQuotes[0] = "All is connected... "; 
  myQuotes[1] = "The best way"; 
  myQuotes[2] = "Your work is to discover"; 
  myQuotes[2] = "If success";

  var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length); 
  $('#quoteHome').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just chain a [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) with a [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), like this:

```
$('#quoteHome').html(myQuotes[myRandom]).hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
$('#quoteHome').hide().html(myQuotes[myRandom]).fadeIn('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#quoteHome').fadeIn();

 $('#quoteHome').fadeIn(1000); //duration in milliseconds

 $('#quoteHome').fadeIn('fast'); //speed
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't be easier.

```
$('#quoteHome').html(myQuotes[myRandom]).fadeIn('slow');
```

Just make sure that `#quoteHome` is set to `display:none` from the getgo.